# psutil Returning Inaccurate RAM Usage Information

Tags: python, hardware, psutil

I am building a hardware utilisation display into my Python project using the [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

In the Python shell, I am getting the RAM usage as shown below:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.virtual_memory()
svmem(total=17179869184, available=6488571904, percent=62.2, used=9150734336, free=20709376, active=6468239360, inactive=6167109632, wired=2682494976)
```

There is a large discrepancy between the `total` value and the actual maximum RAM capacity of my computer, the same applies to the `available` and `used` values.

Below is a cropped screenshot of the RAM usage info in the macOS Activity Monitor app, taken not so long after the `psutil.virtual_memory()` command in the Python shell.

[image: Screenshot snippet of RAM usage in macOS Activity Monitor]

What could be causing these discrepancies, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, surprised there is no answer yet... Did you figure it out?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately. I mainly needed psutil to track my DigitalOcean Droplet's hardware usage. But since DigitalOcean recently implemented "Monitoring" to their APIs, I've been using that instead.

Comment: Ah ok, if it can be of any help I have this issue only on macOS and not on Windows...

Answer (score -1):

There's no discrepancy. Values are in bits.

You can get a human-readable version of those sizes with the `humanize` library. For example, I copied some of the numbers from `psutil` that you posted in your question in this script:

```py
import humanize

print("total: " + humanize.naturalsize(17179869184, binary=True))
print("available: " + humanize.naturalsize(6488571904, binary=True))
print("used: " + humanize.naturalsize(9150734336, binary=True))
print("active: " + humanize.naturalsize(6468239360, binary=True))
print("inactive: " + humanize.naturalsize(6167109632, binary=True))
```

Which prints:

```
total: 16.0 GiB
available: 6.0 GiB
used: 8.5 GiB
active: 6.0 GiB
inactive: 5.7 GiB
```

I believe that this output matches the data shown by your UI.

Note that most hardware vendors and hardware-related tools use [the incorrect units to represent size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion). I.e. you should see GiB instead of GB.